# Automated placement of text and graphics within presentations

Tags: beamer, packages, automation

The `beamer` package creates very professional presentations. Are there any additional packages which can be used with beamer which allows users to focus on content, while leaving TeX to decide where to place everything? E.g.:

- Users make a list, TeX displays attempts two-column mode if there are many short items.
- Users type an outline and specify a prefered density per page for the information, TeX decides when to add page breaks.
- Users link graphics to items in the outline, TeX decides where to position the graphics.

Are these features within the capabilities of `beamer`?

Comment: I don't think that anyone already coded something complicated like this yet. Analyzing content is not trivial and not always fully correct. It is usually simpler to decide the layout themselves and add the required code. However, I could imagine more code templates for standard frame layouts to be very useful.

Comment: And I would imagine the situation is the same across all document classes. There are some options to \penalty for line and page breaks and H option to graphics but that's about it on a global level.  About how ragged or sloppiness you'd LateX take care of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[org-mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-class-export.html) ([example](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-beamer/tutorial.html)) will do some of what you are asking, but not all of it. It will take an outline into a presentation pretty easily, however it won't do things like decide when to change frames for you.  At a minimum, it will hide many of the details of the tex (and you can shove in latex when you need it as well).  However, it requires knowing emacs and org-mode which both have non-trivial learning curves.

I would argue that not splitting things into frames for you is a feature, not a bug as deciding what goes on what slide is arguably part of the content of preparing a talk.